# What is the difference between PhpUnit and PhpRack?

Tags: testing, phpunit

I know they both are for testing but I did not find much information about PhpRack here. Can we use them together in a project? Or only one can serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit is a *unit* testing framework. Unit testing considers the testing of software from the perspective of discreet units of code, such as a class or method.

PHPRack is an *integration* testing framework. Integration testing considers the testing of how separate software modules/systems integrate together in a production environment.

Unit testing and integration testing are not the same thing. A development environment can use both.

Comment: Please note that you are also able to write integration tests using PHPUnit